# Mutex<bool> with an atomic read&write

Tags: rust, concurrency, mutex

I need to have a global boolean flag that will be accessed by multiple threads.

Here is an example of what I need:

```
static GLOBAL_FLAG: SyncLazy<Mutex<bool>> = SyncLazy::new(|| {
    Mutex::new(false)
});

fn set_flag_to_true() {  // can be called by 2+ threads concurrently 
    *GLOBAL_FLAG.lock().unwrap() = true;
}

fn get_flag_and_set_to_true() -> bool {  // only one thread is calling this function
    let v = *GLOBAL_FLAG.lock().unwrap();  // Obtain current flag value
    *GLOBAL_FLAG.lock().unwrap() = true;  // Always set the flag to true
    v  // Return the previous value
}
```

The `get_flag_and_set_to_true()` implementation doesn't feel quite right. I imagine it would be best if I only locked once. What's the best way to do that?

BTW I suppose `Arc<[AtomicBool]>` can also be used and should in theory be faster, although in my particular case the speed benefit will be unnoticeable.

Comment: Just store `GLOBAL_FLAG.lock().unwrap()` in a variable? When it'll be gone at the end of the function, the lock will be released

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conceivably, another thread could come in between when you read `GLOBAL_FLAG` and when you set `GLOBAL_FLAG` to true. To work around this you can directly store the `MutexGuard` ([docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html)) that `GLOBAL_FLAG.lock().unwrap()` returns:

```rust
fn get_flag_and_set_to_true() -> bool {  // only one thread is calling this function
    let mut global_flag = GLOBAL_FLAG.lock().unwrap();
    let v = *global_flag;  // Obtain current flag value
    *global_flag = true;  // Always set the flag to true
    v  // Return the previous value
}
```

`global_flag` will keep the mutex locked until it gets dropped.

Answer (score 7):

> BTW I suppose `Arc<[AtomicBool]>` can also be used and should in theory be faster, although in my particular case the speed benefit will be unnoticeable.

It's not just about benefit in performance, but also in amount of code and ease of *reasoning* about the code. With `AtomicBool` you don't need either `SyncLazy` or the mutex, and the code is shorter and clearer:

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};

static GLOBAL_FLAG: AtomicBool = AtomicBool::new(false);

pub fn set_flag_to_true() {
    GLOBAL_FLAG.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
}

pub fn get_flag_and_set_to_true() -> bool {
    GLOBAL_FLAG.swap(true, Ordering::SeqCst)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8dbd2065ef1fb5bfb767866b70e9141f)

Comment: "ease of reasoning about the code" like Ordering was simple "Indeed, this model is quite complex and known to have several flaws." https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/atomics.html

Comment: @Stargateur It's complex when you need to use it to synchronize otherwise unsafe data structures. In this case, compared to a `Mutex`, it's indeed simple.

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. Indeed, AtomicBoolean is simpler. I imagined I would still need to deal with stuff like `SyncLazy` and `Arc`, but apparently that's not needed.

Comment: @user4815162342 the thing is 3 peoples got convince atomic are simple cause of you. misinformation is bad https://youtu.be/ZQFzMfHIxng

Comment: @Stargateur There is no misinformation in this answer, your accusation has no merit or basis in reality. As I said previously, atomics are simple in case when the atomic operations provided by the type (and implemented through compiler intrinsics) perfectly map to what the code needs to do, as is the case for the OP. Yes, combining atomics with other data loads is complicated, but so are mutexes, rwlocks, condition variables, and parallel programming in general. That is no justification to avoid a perfectly safe API provided by the standard library.

Comment: I didn't say it was a "justification to avoid a perfectly safe API provided by the standard library."